# Getting the true visual bounding box of a WPF element?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

For a simplified version of my problem, I would like to calculate the bounding box of a layout-transformed (possibly even render-transformed) shape, so that I can always fit a rectangle perfectly around the shape, no matter what its rotation or scale may be.  If you can solve this, I will be happy.

The more complex problem is that of calculating the visual bounding box of any framework element.  By 'visual bounding box' I mean the top-most visible pixel within the framework element determines the top-bound, the right-most visible pixel determines the right-bound, etc. If you can solve this, I will be even more happy.

I have tried playing with LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(), but this did not work in the expected manner.  The 'layout slot' was actually MUCH larger than the actual bounds.  I also tried using VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(), but because of the VisualParent of my test shape being protected I could not manage to access this property, and decided to check here before I go any further into it.

I hope that somebody can provide an easy way of getting the true visual bounding box of an element in WPF, that is calculated AFTER all transforms.  If I have not made something clear in my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

```
private Rect GetRectOfObject(FrameworkElement _element)
{
    Rect rectangleBounds = _element.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(
        new Rect(_element.RenderSize);

    return rectangleBounds;
}
```

Maybe this will help out.

Comment: `new Rect(0, 0, _element.Width, _element.Height)` can be simplified to `new Rect(_element.RenderSize)`.

Comment: For me it only worked by using `element.ActualWidth` and `element.ActualHeight`

Answer (score 4):

You will get good results with `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds()` and you can use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` to gain access to the otherwise protected `VisualParent` property.  However what you probably want to do is call `GetDescendantBounds` on the shape itself, not its parent, because in spite of its name, the method returns the bounds of the parent and all of its decendants.

Comment: When I do `GetDescendantBounds()` on my shape, it returns a rectangle that is the bounds of the original non-transformed shape, despite any transformations on the shape.  If I get the parent of the shape using `GetParent()` and then cast over that parent to a Visual, and pass that Visual into the `GetDescendantBounds()`, it returns a rectangle that is much larger than my shape.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not easy, as a control may draw outside its bounds.

But if you assume this doesn't happen you can solve the problem by using `parent.TranslatePoint(point_in_child_coord_system, child)` to transform `(0,0)`, `(child.ActualWidth,0)`, `(child.ActualWidth, child.ActualHeight)` and `(0,child.ActualHeight)` to the parent coord system. Then sort the x and y coordinates of all points and use minimum and maximum values to find the bounding box.

Note: sorting is necessary because of possible child rotation.