# WPF: Bounding Box of Canvas' Children

Tags: c#, wpf

I have dynamically added paths to a canvas object in the codebehind.  How do I get the bounding box of the set of the canvas's children?

I could just iterate through the children, but there has to be a better way:

```
Rect rect;
foreach (var s in canvas.Children)
{
  if (s.Data.Bounds.X > rect.X)
     rect.X = s.Data.Bounds.X;
  ...
}
```

Then once I know the bounding box of the children paths, how do I transform the canvas to center and zoom on the children?

Comment: *"I could just iterate through the children, but there has to be a better way:"*  What other way could there possibly be?  Even if there is a built-in method for you it will do the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Try using VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(). The answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084645/getting-the-true-visual-bounding-box-of-a-wpf-element) may also help.