# How do I find the extents of the contents of a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For my first foray into WPF, I have inherited a user control rendered on a `Canvas`. The control has a lot of user configurable elements (though an input file). This makes the overall size of the control somewhat unpredictable, and it sometimes doesn't fit in its container.

I thought a simple way to get around this would be to allow the content to be whatever size it wants to be, then calculate and apply a `RenderTransform` to fit the content to the container

(How) Can I calculate the 'extents' of the `Canvas` contents so I can figure out the scaling for the transform?

Comment: Actually, it seems I'm duplicating this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419332/wpf-bounding-box-of-canvas-children

Comment: Sounds like perhaps quick work for [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My control actually has three Canvases (title, diagram, and key). I tried wrapping my diagram canvas in a viewbox, but then the canvas is blank??

Comment: I'm wondering if Canvas is even the best way to do what you're doing honestly. Generally when I see people use a canvas they're implementing some pretty sloppy object structure in the first place.

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you need, and your current code and XAML, and we can tell you the proper way to do what you need in WPF.

Comment: Chris, I'm certain that it isn't done the "right" way, but its a project I inherited. I'm contracted to make modifications, and I don't have the time or budget to re-write it. It seems to be unreasonably difficult to do what I was trying - why? I'd have thought it was a straightforward UI type thing to want...

Comment: What kind of content elements are being draw? Are they FrameworkElement or DrawingVisual?

Comment: Fuzhou - Lines, Rectangles, Ellipses, TextBlocks, ArcSegment Paths so Shapes?