# Control taking into account bounding box of child based on transformation (rotation, etc.)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I can't remember if WPF or Silverlight had a control or feature which allowed the control to take into account transformations.

For example, I imagine a control which gets the dimensions based on the single child view bounding box. If the child is a rectangle, the control will have the bounding box of the rotated child:

[image]

Comment: Did you not search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084645/getting-the-true-visual-bounding-box-of-a-wpf-element

Comment: @Andy Thank you for the link, I know about the bounds computation there's no built-in control which does that? Something which works like ViewBox to understand what I mean

Comment: No. No such built in control.